# Thunar not define "_" folders first

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, thunar

Why doesn't Thunar define folders with "_" first? It simply ignores and puts it in alphabetical order! Is this a setting?

It sorts folders first, but does not sort folders with "_" first than other folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is locale dependent. If you want to sort files in ASCII order, use the following command:

```
$ LANG=C thunar
```

This is consistent with `ls` sort order. For example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ touch a b c d _a _b _c
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ls
a  _a  b  _b  c  _c  d
$ LANG=C ls
_a  _b  _c  a  b  c  d
```